# Android repeat function Picasso every 2second

Tags: android

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            loadImageFromUrl(url);

        }
    }, 2000);
    addTouchlistener();
    addButtonListener();
}

private void loadImageFromUrl(String url) {
    Picasso.with(iv.getContext())
            .load(url)
            .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE, NetworkPolicy.NO_STORE)
            .into(iv);
        }
```

the "url" is my http server, i will be receiving the .jpg continuously.
i want repeat the function every 2s to receive the .jpg

In this case, the first time load the image will be delay 2s
but, when i update my photo, it can not show the new photo

i also tried the timer "scheduleAtFixedRate" to repeat but it's not work.

Answer (score 0):

Because a Handler only runs what you post to it once.  It doesn't do so repeatedly.  To do so repeatedly, the runnable needs to repost itself at the end.

Although I suggest you don't do it this way.  How often do you really change the image?  Every few minutes?  Few hours?  Checking every 2 seconds is ridiculous, you're wasting bandwidth 99% of the time.  Use a much longer timer.  Better yet, use push messaging to tell the client when to reload.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example I have in a Fragment, but the logic is the same for an Activity.
I included extra code to turn off the downloads when the app goes onPause().

```
protected Handler programacionTimer;
protected Runnable programacionRunnable;

....

@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (programacionTimer == null) {
                programacionTimer = new Handler();
        }

        if (programacionRunnable == null) {
           programacionRunnable = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                            //Here what you to do (download the image)

                            programacionTimer.postDelayed(this, 2000);

                    }

           };
       }

       programacionTimer.postDelayed(programacionRunnable, 2000);

}


 @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        programacionTimer.removeCallbacks(programacionRunnable);
        programacionRunnable = null;
    }
```

Comment: the handler.postDelayed(this, 2000); need to declared to final and the job still can not repeat...